# Não consigo utilizar algumas fontes no RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, markdown, rmarkdown

Pessoal vocês poderiam me ajudar?

Esse é meu exemplo de codigo do RMarkdown:

```
---
title: "My Title"
header-includes:
      - \usepackage{calligra}
      - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
output:
  pdf_document:
  latex_engine: xelatex    

---

# Section 1

  This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
```

O pdf é gerado normalmente. Mas a fonte não é a que eu quero que é a `calligra`. Até quando eu não uso o `header-includes` e uso `mainfont: calligra` o pdf é gerado mas a fonte nao corresponde a `calligra`

Quando eu vou no TexLive eu vejo q o pacote esta instalado mas mesmo com essses coando o RMarkdown nao puxa essa fonte.

Isso acontece para algumas fontes. Eu vejo que a fonte esta no Tex Live e o RMarkdown não puxa. O que eu preciso fazer?

Muitissimo obrigada!

Laura

Answer (score 4):

A definição de fonte para o uso específico da calligra não é feito da maneira usual. Como ela é definida a partir de um pacote, é necessário determinar de maneira explícita um environment, de modo que esta fonte fique restrita a ele. Abaixo eu coloco um CMR mostrando como fazer isso no RMarkdown.

```
---
title: "My Title"
header-includes:
      - \usepackage{calligra}
      - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
output:
  pdf_document:
  latex_engine: xelatex
---

# Section 1

\begin{calligra}

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, 
PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see
<http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

\end{calligra}

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, 
PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see
<http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sem palavras! Obrigada novamente. Uma pergunta: voce diz q ´Como ela é definida a partir de um pacote, é necessário determinar de maneira explícita um environment, de modo que esta fonte fique restrita a ele` Não entendi. Eu consegui mudar outras fontes sem colocar no enviroment do Rmarkdown. somente com: `header-includes:
      - \usepackage{calligra}
      - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`